# Record audio while playing a sound

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

Is it possible to record audio using AVAudioRecorder and play another audio file with AVAudioPlayer at the same time ?

Comment: Do you want to use the playback from `AVAudioPlayer` as your input source fro recording?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with iOS 6. I have problems doing that in iOS 5.x myself. No information about version prior to 5.x.

To do that, the AudioSession-category has to be set to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"Setting category for AudioSession to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord");
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error setting category for AudioSession:\n\terror: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

The AVAudioRecorder is setup like this:

```
NSString *fileToRecordPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"record.m4a"];
NSURL *fileToRecordURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileToRecordPath];
NSDictionary *settings = @{AVFormatIDKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],
                           AVSampleRateKey: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                           AVNumberOfChannelsKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]};
NSError *error = nil;

AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:self.fileURL settings:settings error:&error];
 if (!audioRecorder) {
    NSLog(@"Error initializing AVAudioRecorder:\n\terror: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
audioRecorder.delegate = self;
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
```

When playing another audio-file (of the same format, m4a) in an AVAudioPlayer everything works fine in iOS 6. In iOS 5 the behaviour is strange. When playing audio or audio-playback is paused, recording cannot be started. When starting to record in first place, playback (of the other file) at the same time is possible though.

After quite some search I couldn't find a way of setting this up correctly. Though I can't believe, it's a bug in iOS, but a missing setting.

So this works with iOS 6, but help for the iOS 5 issue is appreciated a lot ;o)

Comment: I don't. This is the setup of the AVAudioSessionCategory and the AVAudioRecorder. Just use AVAudioPlayer as documented. The, to me, unusual behaviour in iOS 5 is described below.